# How do I make an if statement for my rotating circle in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesmoved

I have this circle and it can rotate 360 degrees to the left and right when the user has their finger on the node and is rotating. I need to figure out how to make an if statement so when it rotates to the left I can add an action and when it rotates to the right I can add another action. Here is the code I have:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if node.name == "rotatecircle" {


            //lets user rotate circle like a knob when there is one finger on node.
            let dy = circle.position.y - location.y
            let dx = circle.position.x - location.x
            let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
            circle.zRotation = angle2

        } 
         } 
          }
```

Comment: I need it so that if the user its rotating to the right I could add an action and if the user is rotating to the left I could add another action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to compare the `angle2` value to the angle value from the previous touch. You can then create an `if` statement that does what you want based on the direction of the rotation.

Some pseudo-code:

In your class:

```
var previousAngle:Double
```

In `touchesMoved`

```
let delta = (angle2 - previousAngle) mod M_PI
if delta > 0 {
    // do action 1
}
else {
    // do action 2
}
previousAngle = angle2
```

You will need some logic to check if this is the first touch. In that case you don't have a `previousAngle` yet, so you don't want to take an action.

Comment: Yea I had add to change some things around and it ended up working. Thank you!